# Is it possible to "Fork" a Git repository from AWS Codecommit into GitHub?

Tags: git, github, aws-codecommit

I've gotten as far from setting the upstream repo in my local Git branch, but without success. Any ideas?

Comment: Your question appears to be a subset of the linked duplicate, if you're having a *specific* problem, please amend your question with the command you're trying to run and whatever error it's outputting.

Comment: The question you've tagged as the answer doesn't really answer his question. It may have the answer somewhere in the response. But it doesn't explain that its possible and what you would do.

Comment: Here's possibly a better question to link to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58466367/how-would-you-fork-an-aws-codecommit-repo-to-another-codecommit-repo