# How would you fork an AWS CodeCommit repo to another CodeCommit repo?

Tags: amazon-web-services, fork, aws-codecommit

In github there is a fork button to fork a repo into a new repo you control.

According to [are git forks actually git clones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286571/are-git-forks-actually-git-clones/6286877#6286877) a github fork is a clone on the server side.

If you read the git-scm [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/GitHub-Contributing-to-a-Project) it specifically says to click the fork button in Github.

I assume because there is no fork button in AWS CodeCommit there is not similar functionality. So, is there a way to do this with the native git cli?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any option in AWS CodeCommit to fork. What you can do is

- Clone the repository.
- Create new repository in AWS CodeCommit.
- Push the code to new repository.

Check this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-migrate-repository-existing.html).

Answer (score 1):

The fork option in GitHub copies the repository in to contributors GitHub account. In code commit all the users belong to the same account. The users are differentiated as IAM users and not as separate accounts. Because of this you don't see separate fork option for every IAM user.

Hassan's answer is the right direction to **migrate** the repo.